# How to discover Bluetooth Classic device in iOS 13 using Core bluetooth Framework

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ios13

I am trying to discover Bluetooth LE and Classic (BR/EDR) device using Core Bluetooth framework in my app which is running on iOS-13. But I am able to find only BLE devices.

How I can scan for Bluetooth Classic devices?

After initialising CBCentralManager and getting the state of CentralManager as powered on, I am scanning for peripheral devices by passing nil in Services and Options.

Code mentioned below :-

```
private var cbManager: CBCentralManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     cbManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
     switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
             cbManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options:nil)

        default:
             os_log("Cleaning up cbManager")
     }
}


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

     if let name = peripheral.name {
         print(name)
     }
}
```

Through this I am only getting BLE devices. Expected result should be : BLE and Classic(BR/EDR) devices list.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `.powerOn` add this to be able to match on a specific service UUID.

```
let matchingOptions = [CBConnectionEventMatchingOption.serviceUUIDs: [uuid-to-classic-bt-device]]
            cbManager.registerForConnectionEvents(options: matchingOptions)
```

Then in the delegate method `centralManager:connectionEventDidOccur:forPeripheral:` you can check for the events `.peerDisconnected` and `.peerConnected` to do something with the peripheral you found.

Apple provides an example of this [Using Core Bluetooth Classic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/using_core_bluetooth_classic)

Comment: How can I get the correct "uuid-to-classic-bt-device" to use with a particular device?

Comment: @AndreaGorrieri were you able to figure out how to get the correct UUID for the classic BT device?

Comment: @sublimepremise I found out that the new BR/EDR support is exclusively for Bluetooth classic devices which implement the GATT profile. The UUID to be provided in the matchingOptions to the "registerForConnectionEvents" method are GATT UUIDs not SDP UUIDs. This means that, with CoreBluetooth, you can't register for connection events for a device which implement A2DP or HFP profiles. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592698/registering-bluetooth-br-edr-classic-connection-in-ios13