# Registering Bluetooth BR/EDR (Classic) connection in iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ios13

From iOS 13 it should be possibile to register for connection events of BR/EDR Bluetooth (Classic) devices. I have followed the instructions provided in the [WWDC keynote](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/), in particular I init my CBCentralManager in this way:

```
func initCentralManager() {

    if self.centralManager == nil{

        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: nil, options:[CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:"myCentralManagerIdentifier"]);

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let matchingOptions = [CBConnectionEventMatchingOption.serviceUUIDs:[CBUUID(string: "1108"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "110A"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "110B"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "110C"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "110D"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "110E"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "110F"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "111F"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "1203"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "1204"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "111E"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "0017"),
                                                                                 CBUUID(string: "0019")]];

            print("REGISTERING FOR BR/EDR CONNECTION EVENTS");
            self.centralManager!.registerForConnectionEvents(options: matchingOptions);

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        };
    }
}
```

Then I implement the callback:

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, connectionEventDidOccur event: CBConnectionEvent, for peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    print("BR/EDR CONNECTED!!!!");

}
```

As suggested in the WWDC video I'm going to the phone settings and I can successfully pair my BR/EDR Bluetooth device (a Bluetooth audio box), however the callback is not fired.

[image]

I don't known exactly the UUID used by my Bluetooth classic device so I have put in the list all the audio-related UUIDs which I found [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery/).

Are the UUID in the correct form? I also tried by adding them using the long notation (e.g, 0000 1108-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB) but nothing happens, the callback still not fire when device is connected in the Bluetooth settings.

How can I get the UUID advertised by my device?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The new BR/EDR support is exclusively for GATT over BR/EDR. It doesn't support other profiles. Do you know that this device supports GATT (most don't)? The service UUIDs are GATT UUIDs, not SDP UUIDs.

Comment: Hi Rob, I didn't know. So it's not possible to know if a connection is made with an A2DP or a HFP device? I think this is part of the external accessory framework as usual...

Comment: We've always been able to know about connections with A2DP or HFP devices; it just comes through AVAudioSession rather than CoreBluetooth. See AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, and AVAudioSession.Port. If you have questions about those, let me know; I use these all the time for tracking audio connections. (It's not related to external accessory. That's just MFi devices that talk iAP2. Most Bluetooth devices don't do that, either.)

Comment: Thank you so much Rob, I'm going to check AVAudioSession. At this point I found the WWDC video quite confusing on this point... they say "audio streaming devices, in-car entertainment systems with hands free calling and various accessories like mouses,  keyboards and gamepads.." "... core bluetooth can now reach out and interact with all of your favorites devices.."

Comment: Yeah…sort of :D I work on some of these devices, and supporting iOS 13 BR/EDR GATT is a big firmware change. We can do it, but it doesn't come for free to the device manufacturer.

Comment: @AndreaGorrieri, Did you find solution for this? I wanted to know whether bluetooth headphone is paired or not?

Comment: @Ranjit see the conversation above with Rob. You have to check AVAudioSession rather than CoreBluetooth when it comes to A2DP devices. The CoreBluetooth BR/EDR support is exclusively for GATT over BR/EDR.